# Add a new Point to a Polygon on Click in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

I have a polygon (square) on the Stage. When a user clicks on any edge of the polygon, a new vertex will be created at that point, increasing the number of edges by 1.

**Problem:** How can you detect a click on the edge/stroke of the Polygon?

After detecting the click, how do you add a new vertex/point to the Polygon at the place it was clicked? I am guessing that if the new point is added to the end of the polygon's `points` array, the polygon may overlap because it draws the polygon in a anti-clockwise manner.

**jsfiddle attempt**: http://jsfiddle.net/frpn7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to "click" to capture the click on the polygon:

```
poly.on('click', function(e) {
```

Unfortunately this will also throw the click event on the inside of the polygon so you will need to create 2 polygons (1 for the inside and one for the border) if you want to have just the border be clickable, otherwise you might try not filling the polygon.

*Edit with how to do that:*

You can do that by combining two shapes together and put them in one group. The first shape will have a border and the second one with no border.

```
        var first_poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
            points: [73, 192, 73, 160, 340, 23, 500, 109, 499, 139, 342, 93],
            fill: '#00D2FF',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 5
        });
        var second_poly = new Kinetic.Polygon({
            points: [73, 192, 73, 160, 340, 23, 500, 109, 499, 139, 342, 93],
            fill: '#00D2FF',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 0
        });

        first_poly.on("click",function(){
            alert("border clicked");
        })
        // add the shape to the layer
        layer.add(first_poly);
        layer.add(second_poly);
        stage.add(layer);
```

Second part borrowed from: [Kinetic JS - Detecting Click on Border of Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458943/kinetic-js-detecting-click-on-border-of-shape)

The third part of re-drawing the polygon will come next.  Speaking abstractly, you can always clear these polygons and simply re-draw the entire polygon again.  First determine the click's new position in the polygon point array.  You can approximate it by looping over each point to determine the 2 closest points and injecting it in between them.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I tried a polygon without a fill (by not specifying a fill) and used the `click` event as suggested, but it still registers a click on both the stroke and the area within the stroke. http://jsfiddle.net/frpn7/2/

Comment: How can I create a polygon within the original polygon to make only the border of the original polygon clickable?

Comment: I edited my answer with some more help and a previously answered question on SO.  Did that help?